# @Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; says The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

Tags: java, spring

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
when i use 
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 
in various classes

the error says :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

|   SendController (field private com. core.services. SendService com. send.api.  SendController. SendService)
↑     ↓
|   SendService (field private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com. core.services. SendService.jdbcTemplate)
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration
↑     ↓
|  securityConfig (field private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com. send.api.configuration.SecurityConfig.jdbcTemplate)
↑     ↓
|  jdbcTemplate
└─────┘
```

so when i used the below code

```
@Autowired
private static JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

cycle dependencies error has gone
but when ever jdbcTemplate template is used it says null pointer exception

Comment: Putting Autowired on a static variable makes no sense. Spring never, ever autowires static fields. Regarding the other problem, you need to read the error message: it explains where the circular dependency is.

Comment: Post the error stack trace as code, not as a quote, so that we can read the dependency graph that is displayed in that message. Have you read it yourself?

Comment: You cannot inject into static variables. Fix the issue. You have a circulair dependency, apparently you are using `JdbcTemplate` in your security config and your service requires this (or vice versa).

Comment: please share the class definition mentioned in the circular dependencies stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You will need setter injection if you want to initialize static variable by dependency injection.